# Pandas Datetime Comparison Failing

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have had a code snippet that has worked historically, which seems to have randomly broke this time around. The error is a type comparison error:

```
df = df[df['loaded'] > last_load]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-62572f9caa45>", line 1, in <module>
    df = df[df['loaded'] > last_mart]

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1201, in wrapper
    pd.DatetimeIndex)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1098, in dispatch_to_index_op
    result = op(left_idx, right)

  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 133, in wrapper
    (type(other), str(other)))

TypeError: <class 'datetime.date'> type object 2018-08-15
```

The code snippet is very straight forward:

```
df['loaded'] = pd.to_datetime(df['loaded'])
last_load = datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(weeks = 2)
df = df[df['loaded'] >= last_load]
```

When looking at the types, I have confirmed that last_load is datetime.date and that df['loaded'] is datetime64[ns].

Looking at the direct data in the dataframe, there has been no random change in formatting or odd new data points. The error seems to be referencing last_load, as that is the date specified by the definition of last_load.

I'm not sure what the issue is. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I had updated pandas since last running this script and, for some reason, pandas no longer converts datetime to str automatically when analyzing. Thus, a simple str wrapper for the datetime fixes the problem. This was for python 3.6.

```
last_mart = datetime.datetime.now().date() - datetime.timedelta(weeks = 2)
df = df[df['loaded'] >= str(last_mart)]
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'sdc_id')
```